# Getting error "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1" from a multi layer json

Tags: java, json, eclipse, gson

Here is the entire class:

```
public class Item {

  static class Page {
    Map <String,String> other_data;
    Map <String,Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>>> specification;
  }

  public static String showName() throws Exception {

    String json = Json.fetch(jsonurl);

    Gson gson = new Gson(); 

    Page result = gson.fromJson(json, Page.class);

    return result.specification.get("result").get("feature").get(0).get("value"); 
    // not working.

    //return result.other_data.get("id"); <-- this one working

  }

}
```

Here's how I fetch the json:

```
public class Json {
    public static String fetch(String urlString) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Connection.auth(urlString)));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

            //return buffer.toString();
            return buffer.toString();

        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have been struggling to get a specific value from a mixed-type JSON feed using `gson`.

```
{
 "other_data":{"id":"150","name":"AA"},
 "specification":{"result":{"feature":[{"name":"attribute A","value":"50"}]}}
}
```

The feed should be valid since I can get `150` from `other_data`

```
`return result.other_data.get("id");`
```

However I can't get the value `50` from the first object of the array `feature`:

```
return result.specification.get("result").get("feature").get(0).get("value");
```

I'm receiving this error:

`Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 37948 path $.specification.`

I think the declaration `Map <String,Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>>> specification;` is incorrect. I did a little debugging by changing it to `Map <String,Object> specification`. I managed to get the stringified object

`{"feature":[{"name":"attribute A","value":"50"}]}`

```
public class Item {

    static class Page {
        String page_type;
        String name;
        Map <String,String> submit_user_data;
        Map <String,Object> specification;
    }


    public static String showName() throws Exception {

        String json = Json.fetch(jsonurl);

        Gson gson = new Gson(); 

        Page td = gson.fromJson(json, Page.class);

        return td.specification.get("result").toString(); // this one works!

    }

}
```

Would anyone tell me what's wrong with the class getting the error?

Comment: Can you hardcode the json string in your code as follows and share the results: String json = "{\"other_data\":{\"id\":\"150\",\"name\":\"AA\"},\"specification\":{\"result\":{\"feature\":[{\"name\":\"attribute A\",\"value\":\"50\"}]}}}";

Comment: @AnupamSaini Is the feed malformed? I don't get error with this: `{\"other_data\":{\"id\":\"150\",\"name\":\"AA\"}}`, but this one getting error: `{\"other_data\":{\"id\":\"150\",\"name\":\"AA\"},\"specification\":{\"result\":‌​{\"feature\":[{\"name\":\"attribute A\",\"value\":\"50\"}]}}}`, although it is valid in JSON Editor.

Comment: `Unterminated object at line 1 column 69 path $.specification`

Comment: Notice that I have only concatenated the json string and escaped the double quotes.

Comment: @AnupamSaini, thank you. I have changed it to  `"{\"other_data\":{\"id\":\"50\",\"name\":\"AA\"},\"specification\":{\"result\":{\"feature\":[{\"name\":\"attribute A\",\"value\":\"50\"}]}}}"` and it works. I forgot to escape the string after fetching the feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently escaping the json string solves the issue:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
  String json = "{\"other_data\":{\"id\":\"150\",\"name\":\"AA\"},\"specification\":{\"result\":{\"feature\":[{\"name\":\"attribute A\",\"value\":\"50\"}]}}}";
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Page result = gson.fromJson(json, Page.class);

  System.out.println(result.specification.get("result").get("feature").get(0).get("value"));
```

}

Comment: I have updated the post with the class that fetched JSON feeds. I guess the class needs to do some escaping before bringing the stringified json feed to gson.